# What exactly does android:screenOrientation do in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, orientation

What does setting `android:screenOrientation` in the activity of the `AndroidManifest.xml` actually do?

If I set it, I can still change my screen orientation - so my question is what is its purpose?

I have a Unity game in portrait, that in one section I want to enable rotation - I can do this from Unity without changing the manifest - so it doesn't appear to be preventing me from changing screen orientation - so what is the purpose of it?

Should my game be `SensorPortrait`, or `FullSensor` because I enable rotation at one point? What will the difference be?

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) indicate that it's used for filtering purposes in the Play store, but surely it serves some other purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:screenOrientation` parameter in the manifest is intended to change the activity orientation.

The reason why it doesn't seem to do anything is because of Unity, it seems. [This forum describes a similar problem and solution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-screen-orientation-issues.250855/):

> We currently do override the Android manifest with a custom one, which works well in most cases. However, I found that when I try to override the screenOrientation value, it doesn't seem to stick through the build pipeline. At some point, I think Unity overwrites the screenOrientation attribute depending on the PlayerSettings values. Unfortunately though, there doesn't seem to be a PlayerSettings configuration that allows us to use the "userPortrait" setting.

```java
    // as an android plugin through unity
    public static int GetAutorotateSetting(Activity activity)
    {
        int setting = 0;
        try
        {
            setting = Settings.System.getInt(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Unity", "Couldn't retrieve auto rotation setting: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return setting;
    }
```

```cs
    // on the unity side:
    public static bool AllowAutorotation()
    {
        bool doAutorotation = false;
    #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidJavaClass unity = newAndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
     
        using(AndroidJavaClass andClass = new AndroidJavaClass("PUT YOUR JAVA CLASS HERE"))
        {
            int allowAutorotation = andClass.CallStatic<int>("GetAutorotateSetting", unityActivity);
            if(allowAutorotation == 0)
            {
                doAutorotation = false;
            }
            else
            {
                doAutorotation = true;
            }
        }
    #endif
        return doAutorotation;
    }
```

The person who suggested this solution [also put a .unitypackage file on github](https://github.com/hvs-clark/unity-android-rotation-lock).